# I have issues with handling big CSV files in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'm using JSON to handle csv files but when the files are too big my PC starts having problems so I'm asking for a small piece of code on how to read the CSV file and insert it into the database (mysql) line by line without overwhelming the memory

Comment: Please share your code. We're glad to help you with your existing code, but we won't write it all for you.

Comment: I'm using mobile xD and i just want a small piece of code coz i don't really know how to start but I'll write my code that I'm having issues with

Comment: That's not how SO works. It's not a free coding service. If you don't have access to your current code right now, then I would recommend deleting the question and come back when you do.

Comment: Yeah i know, i just wanted a tutorial on how to do so and sorry again man

Comment: Asking for external resources such as tutorials is considered off-topic here. Please go read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I would recommend that you read through [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) or your future questions might be downvoted and closed. The fact that you say _"Yeah i know"_ doesn't make it better, rather the opposite.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use this code and open a stream to read a file:

```
$newfilename = "redirect.csv";
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["csvfile"]["tmp_name"], "img/" . $newfilename);
$file = fopen($filename,"r");
while(($entry = fgetcsv($file, 50000, ";")) !== FALSE)
{
    //your code here
}
```

Comment: "Gimme code"-type questions are off-topic and should not be answered. A good question includes their attempts. If you do answer them anyway, the OP and future visitors will just keep asking off-topic questions. Here's a good post about it: [Should I answer off-topic questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133552/should-i-answer-off-topic-questions)

Comment: Thanks dude that was exactly what i was looking for

Comment: I cannot use internet on the computer I'm working on and posting this question from my mobile, sorry for that